# Is there a difference between use of _WINDOWS_ and _WIN32 / _WIN64 macros?

Tags: c++, windows, macros, conditional-compilation

Is there a difference between:

```
#if defined(_WIN32) || defined(_WIN64)
```

and:

```
#ifdef _WINDOWS_
```

I know that it is necessary to use `defined()`  when there is more than 1 condition.

Comment: side note: `_WIN32` is also defined for 64 bit platform. See [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/predefined-macros?view=msvc-170): `_WIN32 Defined as 1 when the compilation target is 32-bit ARM, 64-bit ARM, x86, or x64. Otherwise, undefined.`! So you do not need do `#if defined(_WIN32) || defined(_WIN64)` it  is enough just `#if defined(_WIN32)`.

Comment: Historically, `_WIN32` was added when moving from 16-bit Windows to 32-bits. So it basically means "not 16-bit".

Answer (score 8):

Yes, there *is* a difference. The `_WIN32` and `_WIN64` tokens are defined (conditionally) depending on what platform is being targeted. The former (`_WIN32`) will be defined for x86, x64, ARM and ARM-64 architectures; the latter (`_WIN64`) will be defined *only* for the two 64-bit architectures.

However, the `_WINDOWS_` macro will *always* be defined if the "Windows.h" header file is included by a given source file. It is used (in that header) as a 'guard', to prevent multiple inclusions of its body. A *very* trimmed-down version of that header is:

```cpp
/* ...
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
   ...
    Master include file for Windows applications.

--*/

#ifndef _WINDOWS_
#define _WINDOWS_

// ...
// <body of Windows.h>
// ...


#endif /* _WINDOWS_ */
```

Also, when using the MSVC compiler (and, possibly, some others), the `_WIN32` and `_WIN64` macros are **predefined** by the compiler (i.e. no header *needs* to be included for them to be defined for their relevant target platforms).

---

Just to add to the confusion, MSVC also adds a `_WINDOWS` macro (note the lack of the trailing underscore) by default, when creating new projects that target Windows (this is not formally predefined, but is one of the default, per-project "Preprocessor Definitions" in the projects' properties.

Comment: "_the latter (_WIN64) will be defined only for the two 64-bit architectures._" In this case, it would be ALWAYS safer to use `_WIN32` to check if the code is compiling on Windows, right?

Comment: @TonySalimi Sure. There are other target platform-specific macros but I think the `_WIN32` is safest. Even for compilers that *don't* pre-define it, the standard Windows headers will likely do their best to add it, depending on some of those other platform-specifying tokens.

Comment: Is there a macro for ARM64 platforms? I get `_WIN32` is for x86 builds (Intel/AMD 32-bit) and `_WIN64` is for x64 builds (Intel/AMD 64-bit), but is there a macro for the ARM 64-bit architecture? It seems odd to use the `_WIN32` macro for ARM64 builds because `_WIN32` is for 32-bit builds.

Comment: Oh I may have misunderstood the language above in the post. Correct me if I am wrong, but I should use `_WIN64` for ARM 64-bit builds and the macros `_WIN32` and `_WIN64` don't infer **only** Intel/AMD anymore. They now include ARM and ARM 64-bit respectively too. I guess the legacy of Windows got me confused.

Comment: @CodeDoggo You can use `_M_ARM` and `_M_ARM64` for ARM and ARM64 builds and `_M_IX86` and `_M_X64` for x86/x64. (In MSVC, at least.)